# How do I turn my script into a remotely hosted app?

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, uptime

As part of a research project, I have a script that consumes tweets from twitter into a locally hosted mongodb database:

```
import json
import pymongo
import tweepy

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        super(tweepy.StreamListener, self).__init__()

        self.db = pymongo.MongoClient().test

    def on_data(self, tweet):
        self.db.tweets.insert(json.loads(tweet))

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        return True # Don't kill the stream


sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(api))
sapi.filter(track=['snowden'])
```

To improve uptime, I would like to do two things: i) run this script remotely, and ii) store the consumed tweets in the cloud. However, being completely new to all things programming, I am lost as to what I should do to achieve my goals. What are my next steps? What is the "path of least resistance" to uptime?

Answer (score 2):

Heroku is a cloud platform supports Python and MongoDB which I'd recommend you use. [This link](https://gist.github.com/kennethreitz/2032410) provides a working reference on how to do this.

Here are another couple of links to help you out:

1) [Python database WITHOUT using Django (for Heroku)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640532/python-database-without-using-django-for-heroku)

2) [How can I use the mongolab add-on to Heroku from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859532/how-can-i-use-the-mongolab-add-on-to-heroku-from-python)

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK. Do I need to create a Github repo for my script and then deploy it to Heroku? So far, I've been running my script straight from Terminal on my (mac) computer.

Comment: Not required...Heroku has Git support built in. Check out this Getting Started tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python

Comment: Thank you for the link to the Heroku Getting Started Tutorial. Following the steps in the tutorial, I've successfully set up a clean flask environment, written a helloworld.py app and deployed this app to Heroku. So far so good. However, I have no idea how to modify my source code (see original question) so that it will run as a Flask app. Any thoughts?